# Rubber gasket maker on rocker cover

Tags: engine, gasket, valve-cover, gasket-maker

After recently taking my car to have a new rocker cover gasket fitted as it was badly leaking I noticed the guy who did it put a ton of gasket maker on the rocker cover when he sealed it, heavens knows why; I gave him a new gasket so it shouldn’t really be needed. Perhaps he used it to improve the seal.

What I am worried about is what if a piece of this gasket maker broke off inside the rocker cover what sort of havoc would it wreak inside my engine?

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rubber gaskets typically seal well.  Cork ones are hit or miss.  If the valve cover is stamped steel, its normal to use gasket maker rather than the gasket.

If a piece did fall off inside the engine, the oil would likely flush it down to the oil pan and it would be caught in the oil pickup's screen.

Comment: I'm also thinking it would not be a big deal, so spot on. It looks ugly, but as long as it works (stops the oil leak), no big deal.

Comment: tell me to shut up if I’m way over thinking this but could this stuff block the pickup screen over time or would it just be held against it until the next oil change where it's drained out. I guess what I’m asking is how mighty is the oil pumps suck, can it pull it through if it needed to or would it block it completely. Also should I clean my oil pick up screen from time to time or should it not get blocked at all throughout the cars life.

Comment: should clean out next oil change.  its not normal for bits to break off in the engine.  Shouldn't be enough to block the screen.